# Retornar a página anterior com o botão voltar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um botão voltar que supostamente deveria retornar à página anterior, independente de qual seja esta página no sistema. Como posso fazer isto utilizando o MVC 4? O `returnURL` tem algo haver com esta funcionalidade?

Comment: Depende ... isso pode ser o `window.history.back()` que você deseja implementar com JAVASCRIPT, isso é fator independente de tecnologia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "ActionDeVoltar", "ControllerQualquer", new { returnUrl = this.Request.UrlReferrer }, null)
```

Coloque no seu `Controller` comum uma `Action` assim:

```
public ActionResult ActionDeVoltar(string returnUrl)
{
    if (returnUrl != "") return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Não é tão elegante quanto o JavaScript, mas pelo menos gera HTML estático.

Comment: Estou tentando utilizar o javascript, o problema é que quando o utilizo na página, ela dá um refresh. Mas quando abro o console do Chrome e digito o código, ele funciona...

Comment: O código acima também está atualizando a página apenas...

Comment: Desculpe. Variável errada. Veja agora.

Comment: Agora sim! Mass... por que devo retornar apenas se o returnUrl == "" ?

Comment: Foi mal. É o sono. Já corrigi.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="@Request.UrlReferrer" class="btn btn-default">Voltar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal fazer o seu custom `HtmlHelper` da forma que desejar?

Bom, para isso, crie uma classe de `Extensions` para criar o nosso `Helper`. Caso não saiba do que estou falando, [este link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) possui uma breve explicação do que é e como desenvolver um Custocustom `HtmlHelper`.

Para o exemplo e chamei a minha de `HtmlExtensions`, e ela ficou desta forma:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ReturnActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,string linkText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var url = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

            var link = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText,null, htmlAttributes);

            string replacedString = Regex.Replace(link.ToString(), "href=\"([^ \"]*)", "href=\"" + url);

            return new MvcHtmlString(replacedString);
        }
    }
```

E em sua `View`, basta chamar o custom `Helper`.

```
@Html.ReturnActionLink("voltar")
```

Neste `Helper` eu simplesmente crio um `Html.ActionLink` normal e substituo o valor pelo `UrlReferrer` mostrado nas respostas anteriores.

Com isso você pode fazer o que quiser, customizar class, tag, etc. Até mesmo se quiser usar o `window.history.back()` em um `onclick()` é possível.