# É possível inserir o caractere '#' (hash) nas rotas do MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

É possível inserir o caractere **#** (hash) nas rotas do MVC? Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em MVC no qual uma das especificações é o uso de **#** nas rotas do MVC.

É possível realizar isso nativamente? Existe algum meio de contornar a situação?

Grato!

Comment: Você quer usar como um caractere normal? Ou seja, quer escapar o caractere e não ser interpretado pelo navegador? Tentou usar %23?

Comment: Como um caractere normal. Como se fosse uma rota de SPA' (angular). Exemplo: http://mydomain.com.br/#/cars?id=10.

Comment: Tentou o que eu falei?

Comment: Não deu certo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já foi dito, com rotas não é possível fazer isso.

Uma forma de fazer isso, seria alterar o retorno do `Controller` para um `Redirect()` para o página desejada.

Algo como isso:

```
 return Redirect("/Home/Contact#contato");
```

Ou isso:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Contact", "Home") + "#contato");
```

Lembrando que isso colocará apenas "uma âncora" no final da URL. não sei ao certo o que deseja fazer com isso.

Caso queira mais detalhes, [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5567721/4843158) possui mais respostas sobre oq ue você perguntou.

> Nota: Caso opte por usar o `Redirect()`, tome cuidado. Se a requisição para a mesma `Action()`, irá causar um **Loop Infinito**.

Caso queira fazer isso no cliente, você pode [customizar o HtmlHelper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145698/20615) e criar o seu próprio, com a rota desejada.

Answer (score 3):

> É possível realizar isso nativamente? Existe algum meio de contornar a situação?

Não. `#` é um símbolo reservado para navegadores para indicar âncoras e não pode fazer parte de rotas.

Como só o cliente possui acesso ao que vem depois de `#`, não faz muito sentido definir rotas com ele. Só confundiria o navegador e o JavaScript não funcionaria direito.